# Filling form in Chrome using Applescript and Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

Full disclosure: I am very much a neophyte Applescript person (and Javascript).  I have spent several hours trying to figure this out on my own, searching the Internet and trying many variations of Applescript, but no luck.  I'm at a dead end without some help.

I'm modifying an Applescript that opens several web pages to lookup a word in Latvian - a language that I'm studying.  The word I'm searching goes in the URL for most pages (i.e. Google Translate); however, the best dictionary I've found uses a simple form to enter a word - I can't embed the word in the URL.  So, I've been trying to figure out how to enter the word on the form and "click" submit (Meklēt=search on the page in question).

The website in question is: http://www.latvianforyou.com/cgi-bin/l.pl

Here's the latest version of the Applescript I've tried:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay 3
    execute javascript "document.getElementsByName('word').childNodes[0].value={{!VAR1}}"
    execute javascript "document.forms[0].submit()"
end tell
```

The script doesn't seem to do anything.  I get a "missing variable" back in the Applescript editor; I'm not sure that's an error.  I've read that it simply means a null value was returned.

VAR1 is the word I'm searching/looking up and I know that variable is working - at least in the URLs of the other sites I'm searching.  In any case, I have also tried directly entering the search term: "...value="akmens"" and "...value=123"" (akmens is "stone" in Latvian).  However, nothing is entered into the search field.

I used the Inspect feature within Chrome to find the name of the input field, which is "word": ().

The page does open with my Applescript; it is the last tab in a new Chrome window (the other tabs in that Chrome window are the other sites that I'm searching).  The script above switches over to Chrome to the correct tab - with the site I'm having trouble with.  IOW - I don't *think* that selecting the correct Chrome window/tab is an issue.

I'm hoping that my mistake is relatively simple/easy to fix.  If not - if entering some text in this field and "clicking" submit/search is much more complex, then I may just bag it and enter the word on that site manually.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved this but I have 2 possible solutions for you

1. pass in a full url such as
   http://www.latvianforyou.com/cgi-bin/l.pl?word=1234
2. Use safari as I think Chrome is now broken
   set thejavascript to "correctly_formatted_js"
   tell application "Safari"
   activate
   do JavaScript (thejavascript & ";") as text in document 1
   end tell


   JAYTEE